# How to find wavefunction in this case?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, coordinate-systems, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian

We have a two interacting particle system, with Hamiltonian as:

$$H_{s y s}=\frac{\mathbf{p}_{1}^{2}}{2 m_{1}}+\frac{\mathbf{p}_{2}^{2}}{2 m_{2}}+V\left(\mathbf{r}_{1}, \mathbf{r}_{2}\right).$$

we reduce it to two non-interacting fictitious particles, one moving freely other in a central field, thus the system has Hamiltonian,  $H_{s y s}=\frac{\mathbf{P}^{2}}{2 M}+\frac{\mathbf{p}_{r e l}^{2}}{2 \mu}+V(\mathbf r)$ with the operator relations as:

$\mathbf{R}=\frac{m_{1} \mathbf{r}_{1}+m_{2} \mathbf{r}_{2}}{m_{1}+m_{2}}$

$\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{r}_{2}-\mathbf{r}_{1}$

$\mathbf{p}_{r e l}=\frac{m_{1} \mathbf{p}_{2}-m_{2} \mathbf{p}_{1}}{m_{1}+m_{2}}$,

$\mathbf{P}=\mathbf{p}_{1}+\mathbf{p}_{2}$

We solve $H|E\rangle=E|E\rangle$ for the two non-interacting particles and find the wavefunction $\psi_{s y s}(\mathbf{R}, \mathbf{r})=\psi_{C M}(\mathbf{R}) \psi_{r e l}(\mathbf{r})$.

**My question(s):**

How do we find the wavefunction in terms of $\mathbf r_1,\mathbf  r_2$? We can't just invert $\mathbf{R}=\frac{m_{1} \mathbf{r}_{1}+m_{2} \mathbf{r}_{2}}{m_{1}+m_{2}}$

$\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{r}_{2}-\mathbf{r}_{1}$ and use them in the wavefunction  because they are operator relations.

Comment: When transforming to the center-of-mass coordinates, one should transform not only the Hamiltonian, but also the wave function. Once you have done it yourself, the reverse transformation will be obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: The operator relations can still be inverted. Moreover, $\hat{\bf r}_1$, $\hat{\bf r}_2$, $\hat{\bf R}$ & $\hat{\bf r}$ are mutually commuting operators, so one can choose a basis (namely, the Schrödinger position representation), where they are simultaneously diagonalized.